# How to update the elemends in a javafx scene?

Tags: javafx

How to update or refresh the screen, each time I press the load new scene in javafx 
in swing we can use the validate(), reValidate()  to refresh screen !. but How can I update the screen containts  in javafx?

Comment: No need to update.

Comment: Yes, it should needed. Because I am a blind person, I am writing codes and running programs through screen reader software. I already done the java programming for the basic software developments.
now I started to learn the GUI Programming, but whenever I made more than 1 scene in a javafx, I need to refresh the screen to read the content on the screen through the screen reader short cutsAfter reaching the second scene through any action.
I think there is a function is happening behind this short cut, it might be a system function for screen updation.
If you have any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that in JavaFX. The screen is updated automatically each time when something in the scene graph changes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this problem is in the part of my screen reader software.
It haven’t reading after changing the scenes, if I need to read the elements or controls in the scene, definitely I need to use the short cut key for refresh screen for my screen reader software.
Therefore, I need a solution through java that what I asked the question!
There is a system function is calling while I invoking the refresh shortcuts for my screen reader.
Is there any such system function for screen refresh or screen updation?